# Converting a massive string in a table format to a table

Tags: html, arrays, string, pre

Say a webpage has this as the only thing on it:

```
<pre style="word-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre-wrap;">
"[{"Asset":1112, "Name":"Test"}, {"Asset":223, "Name":"Drill"}]"
</pre>
```

How would I turn that string into a table that I can access and draw from? Even even if I find it, I still have no clue how to convert the string into a table that I access.

I know that document.getElementsByTagName("PRE"); will return the massive string, but I'm a little lost after that.

I was searching through hundreds of pages trying to find a good example for what I need to do. Here is one such example:
http://www.roblox.com/catalog/json?browse.aspx?Subcategory=2&Keyword=&CurrencyType=0&pxMin=0&pxMax=0&SortType=2&SortAggregation=0&SortCurrency=0&LegendExpanded=true&Category=2&PageNumber=1

Comment: Hi user3339797, do you feel as if I answered your question completely? If so, please don’t forget to mark my answer as "accepted" by clicking the gray checkmark to the left of the answer. If your question hasn't been fully answered, please elaborate on what else you need to know so the community can provide you with further help! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a classic JSON parsing problem. The page you linked is actually text only - the `pre` formatting you're seeing is only the browser's default styling. If you view page source, you will be able to see that the page is pure **text only** JSON.

So what you will need to do is to fetch that page into your application using an [`XMLHttpRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest), then once you have the string you will be able to parse it using the inbuilt JSON utilities.

Here is a **Live Demo** showing you how to turn the raw JSON string data into a usable data structure once you have it in your application:

```js
var str = '[{"Asset":1112, "Name":"Test"}, {"Asset":223, "Name":"Drill"}]';
var obj = JSON.parse(str);
var output = "Asset 1: " + obj[0].Asset + ", Name: " + obj[0].Name + "<br />";
output += "Asset 2: " + obj[1].Asset + ", Name: " + obj[1].Name;
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = output;
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```

JSFiddle Version: https://jsfiddle.net/q0wdz4vz/1/

Note that the outer JSON object is an array. For the first line I used `obj[0]` to retrieve the first object in the array, then used `.Asset` to get its asset number. Likewise with `.Name`, and the second object.